# Accessing a nested node in an XML load by SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML file with this structure.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <COMMUNITIES>
    <COMMUNITY ID="c001">
      <NAME>Town Services</NAME> 
      <TOP>50</TOP> 
      <LEFT>50</LEFT> 
      <WIDTH>200</WIDTH> 
      <HEIGHT>300</HEIGHT> 
      <URLS>
          <URL ID="U001">
              <NAME>Google.com</NAME>
              <URL>http://www.google.com</URL>
          </URL>
          <URL ID="U002">
              <NAME>Bing.com</NAME>
              <URL>http://www.bing.com</URL>
          </URL>
          <URL ID="U003">
              <NAME>Yahoo.com</NAME>
              <URL>http://www.yahoo.com</URL>
          </URL>
          <URL ID="U004">
              <NAME>Aol.com</NAME>
              <URL>http://www.aol.com</URL>
          </URL>
      </URLS> 
      </COMMUNITY>
</COMMUNITIES>
```

I am able to get to the first-level elements NAME through HEIGHT with this script.

```
<?php

function get_nodes() {
// load SimpleXML
$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('communities.xml', null, true);

foreach($nodes as $node) // loop through 
{

        echo "<div id = '".$node['ID']."' class= 'comdiv ui-widget-content' style = 'top: ".$node->TOP."px; left: ".$node->LEFT."px; width: ".$node->WIDTH."px; height: ".$node->HEIGHT."px;'> \n";

        echo "   <p class = 'comhdr editableText ui-widget-header'>".$node->NAME."</p>\n";

        echo "   <a href='#' onClick=\"delete_div('".$node['ID']."');\">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
        echo "   <a href='#' onClick=\"add_url('".$node['ID']."');\">Add URL</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";

        echo "</div> \n";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').resizable();\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable();\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable('option', 'handle', '.comhdr');\n";
        echo "</script>\n";


        $nodeid = $node['ID'];

        $xurls = $node->URL; // WHAT IS THE WAY TO GET TO <URLS> and LOOP THOUGH ALL <URL> NODES
        $nurls = sizeof($xurls);

}
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "  $('.editableText').editableText();\n";
        echo "</script>\n";

   return;
}

echo get_nodes();
?>
```

How do I get an array of the  nodes contained in the  node?  Once I get that array, I must retrieve the NAME and URLC for each URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions.  They all gave me more information than I had before about accessing nested nodes.  I went with a modified version of Jamie's suggestion.  With each community node I accessed the URLS with this loop.

```
    foreach($node->URLS->URL as $url)
    { 
       // Print HTML elements with the URL information
    }
```

Here is the working script in its entirety.

```
<?php

function get_nodes() {
// load SimpleXML
$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('communities.xml', null, true);

foreach($nodes as $node) // loop through 
{

        echo "<div id = '".$node['ID']."' class= 'comdiv ui-widget-content' style = 'top: ".$node->TOP."px; left: ".$node->LEFT."px; 

width: ".$node->WIDTH."px; height: ".$node->HEIGHT."px;'> \n";

        echo "   <p class = 'comhdr editableText ui-widget-header'>".$node->NAME."</p>\n";

        echo "   <a href='#' onClick=\"delete_div('".$node['ID']."');\">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
        echo "   <a href='#' onClick=\"add_url('".$node['ID']."');\">Add URL</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";

        echo "</div> \n";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').resizable();\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable();\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable('option', 'handle', '.comhdr');\n";
        echo "</script>\n";

        foreach($node->URLS->URL as $url)
        { 
           echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Node: ".$node['ID']." has URLS:".$url['ID']." ".$url->NAME." ".$url->URL." '); 

</script>";
        }


}
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "  $('.editableText').editableText();\n";
        echo "</script>\n";

   return;
}

echo get_nodes();

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

A little bit longer but works for me

```
$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('communities.xml', null, true);

foreach($nodes->COMMUNITY->URLS->URL as $url) {
 echo $url['ID'];
 echo $url->NAME;
 echo $url->URL;
}
```

Comment: I had to make a slight modification to the code since I was interested in the urls for a specific node.  Within the `foreach ($nodes... ) {} loop`, I retrieved the URLS like this `foreach($node->URLS->URL as $url) {}`. This worked great. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are exactly looking for but that could be useful:

`$node->children();` returns the children of the node and you can easily loop through:

```
foreach ($node->URLS->children() as $child)
{
    print $child->URL;
}
```

HTH

Comment: I get an error for children(): `
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::children() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\community\get_nodes.php on line 76'

Comment: Try it with $node->URLS->children(). My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
$urls = $node->xpath('URLS/URL');
foreach($urls as $url) {}
```

But it seems that you have error in your code. Instead of $node->URL**S**; you use $node->URL;. Try to replace.

Comment: I get an error for that: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::xpath() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\community\get_nodes.php on line 67`

Comment: It seems that you have error in your code. Instead of $node->URLS; you use $node->URL;. Try to replace.